# Ensure constraints before opening value relation QField

Tags: qfield, relationship-class

My QGIS Project is made of many obligatory non-null fields and value relation widgets. While I'm able to use value relation widget along my forms in QGIS, in QField I need to fill all fields to be able to use my value relations. It's inconvenient because I need to place all of these at the end of my form, so not in the order in which they will be take on the field. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand.  Are the value_relation widgets locked until you fill in the other fields? Perhaps you can provide a sample project to inspect.

Comment: Hi Oisin, yes that is the problem. I will share you QField data folder. Is this normal in your opinion? I could also share a QGIS project, let me know if you want to see it too. Thank you.

Comment: https://we.tl/t-VkO9Ej4vY3